# Alternatives of " Find OEP by section hop " for X64dbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, malware, ida, x64dbg

Now, I am starting to learn about malware unpacking. In the practical malware analysis book they told about the " Find OEP by section hop ".The program will hit a breakpoint just before the OEP executes. Most of the cases in which I am using xdbg and ollydebug are only for 32 bits. There are any alternatives to " Find OEP by section hop " available for x64dbg?

alternative plugins.